# Proof of Exponential function $a^n$

Tags: polynomials

How can I prove that $$\sum_{n=N}^M a^n =  \frac{a^M - a^{N+1}}{1-a}$$ for $a$ not equal to $1$ and $$\sum_{n=N}^M a^n = M-N+1$$ for $a = 1$

Comment: Second sum looks wrong. Should equal $M - N + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Can you verify this ?

$$ (1-a)(1+a+a^2+\cdots + a^M)=1-a^{M+1} $$

Comment: Yes I can, but I can't see where that gets me.

Comment: $(1-a)(1+a+\cdots + a^N) =1-a^{N+1}\ (M>N)$. So we consider the subtraction between two equations : $$ (1-a)(a^M + \cdots + a^{N+1} ) = a^{N+1} - a^{M+1}$$